# Problem with PDE Energy inegral and a limit

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have the problem :$$b^2w_{tt}+w_t=\vec{\nabla}^2 w, \quad \vec{r}\in D\subset \mathbb{R}^n,\quad b>0$$
$$w(\vec{r},t)=0,\quad \vec{r}\in \partial D,\quad t>0$$
$$w(\vec{r},0)=0,\quad \vec{r} \in D$$
$$w_{t}(\vec{r},0)=b^{-c}g(\vec{r}),\quad \vec{r} \in D$$
$D$ bounded,open and connected with normal $\partial D$, $c<1$ and $g$ is a normal function and does not conclude $b$ .I have proved that the energy integral:$$E(t)=\int_{D}\left(b^{2}w_{t}^2+(\vec{\nabla}w)^2\right)dv(\vec r )$$ is declining.I have to prove that:$$\lim_{b\rightarrow 0}\int_{D}(\vec{\nabla}w(\vec{r},t))^2 dv(\vec{r})=0$$
I have proved that :$$0\leq\int_{D}(\vec{\nabla}w)^2 dv(\vec r)\leq E(t )\leq E(0)=b^{2-c}\int_{D}g(\vec r )dv(\vec r)$$
My question is if I can say that the integral $\int_{D}g(\vec r )dv(\vec r)$ is finite ?because if it is  I can take limits  in the last inequality above and I will have finished.Any help please?

Comment: I do not get the point. $g$ is a given function, so your question depends if you assume it is an integrable function on $D$, or not. Btw what do you mean by a "normal" function, and what do you mean by not "concluding" $b$, you mean not depending on $b$?

Comment: I mean that g is not depended on b